# Cannot override CORS policy. What i'm do wrong?

Tags: javascript, apache, cors, cesiumjs

Server returns `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` but with no result. Still having error what CORS policy blocked. Please help guys

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at the wrong URL.

The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is on `http://182.168.0.123/cesium/etc`

The error message relates to a request for `http://192.168.0.123:8080/list/`.

---

The permission to access the resource has to come from the resource.

The server providing the JavaScript file itself can't give permission for that JS to access a different origin.